# Convert A Byte[] Array to Image in Xamarin Forms

Tags: arrays, image, xamarin.forms, image-conversion

Before asking this question I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution that suits mine.

In `Xamarin.Forms` I have a `byte[]` array and I want to Convert that `byte[]` array to an `Image`. How can I achieve that, this is what I tried:

**In Front End(XAML):**

```js
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Olive" x:Name="imagePanel">
    <Image x:Name="PdfImage" Aspect="AspectFill" IsVisible="true"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**In Code Behind(C#):**

```js
byte[] imageAsBytes = Constant.jsonPDF;

var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
PdfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));

imagePanel.Children.Add(PdfImage);
```

But My problem is image is not displaying.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the byte[] a jpg or png?

Comment: Actually that i don't know... `Constant.jsonPdf` contains the value and is coming from server. When i debug i can only see the `byte[694753]`.

Comment: you should verify that - write it to disk and then look at it with an image viewer, or download it to your desktop with curl or your browser.  If it's not a valid image type it won't display in the Image control

Comment: Ok Thanks... I Saved the byte array to gallery using `DependencyService` but i'm only getting a blank screen ;(

Comment: it sounds like it's either a bad image, or in some unsupported format

Comment: So how can i find out whether the format is supported or not

Comment: either jpg or png

Comment: yeah i'm saving the file as `.png` extension

Comment: if the byte[] is not valid image data it doesn't matter what extension you use when saving

Answer (score 11):

(XAML):

```
 <Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="IncidentImageData" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="175"/>
```

viewModel.SImageBase64 is a byte[]

Code Behind(C#):

```
var stream1 = new MemoryStream(viewModel.SImageBase64);
IncidentImageData.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
```

simply i have done like this and image has shown.

Comment: This doesn't work and is spoken about hundreds of times on the Xamarin Github and Microsoft Devs pages because `ImageSource.FromStream()` requires a brand new MemoryStream to be created within it's lambda function. You're very lucky if this worked for you but 9 times out of 10 this solution won't work.

Comment: The slightly more long winded, but working way of doing it similarly to this is by converting the MemoryStream to a byte array and then using that byte array to create another MemoryStream within the lambda function of FromStream()

Answer (score 9):

## A Potential Fix

I know this thread is 2 years old now but I thought i'd post a working solution here for anyone who's also struggling with this. Just spent half a day researching and trying to solve an identical problem, the way the code was written on this post helped me greatly as it is almost 100% correct. You just need to provide the MemoryStream as a return from a lambda function within the `FromStream()` method.

Change this:

```
PdfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
```

To:

```
PdfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
     return new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
});
```

And the snippet should be working as of Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2012

Full Code:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Constant.jsonPDF;

PdfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
     return new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
});

imagePanel.Children.Add(PdfImage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution it did work really good. I just had to change ´imagePanel.Children.Add(PdfImage)´ to ´PdfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return new MemoryStream(qrCodeAsBitmapByteArr);
            });´. Without your answer I wouldn't be able success. Thanks a lot. EDIT: My bad, you already did that and i overlooked it.

Comment: no worries! if this helped then be sure to mark the thread as solved!

Comment: I am not the OP but I gave you an upvote. :D

Comment: @MatthewSwallow , stream1 is no longer needed

Comment: Could have simplified like - 
PdfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));

Comment: Not working it shows empty @MatthewSwallow

Comment: @DevXam is your byte array also empty?

Comment: @MatthewSwallow, no byte array not empty.

Comment: I have to convert the SVG image to a byte array, and the Byte array to an image source. Because SVG image value dynamically changes I don't know how to set image source that's why I follow above fix but working its shows empty.

Answer (score 4):

Use this Code :

```
imgUserImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(userList.Single().ProfilePhoto));
```

Here profile photo type is byte[]

```
public byte[] ProfilePhoto { get; set; }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22067253)